# ActiveRecord missing join tables when performing subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm encountering strange behaviour when using subqueries with joins in Rails. While generating a non-subquery works fine, Rails seems to 'forget' about the join tables when constructing the full query.

Here is an example. Please don't pay too much attention to which tables I use, it's only an example as the actual query I'm using is a bit too complex.

This one works:

```
2.4.0 :015 > User.all.includes(:company).where(companies: {id: 0})
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.`id` AS t0_r0, [..]
    `companies`.`id` AS t1_r0, [..]
    FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` ON `companies`.`id` =
    `users`.`company_id` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 0 ORDER BY
    `users`.`username` ASC
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

But when I wrap it all in a where:

```
2.4.0 :016 > User.where(id: User.all.includes(:company).where(
companies: {id: 0}).references(:companies))
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`
    IN (SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 0 ORDER
    BY `users`.`username` ASC) ORDER BY `users`.`username` ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
'companies.id' in 'where clause'
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or can Rails just not deal with joins in subqueries?

Also, I'm not in a position where I can use joins(). I also need to return records for which the join does not yield any results, therefore needing includes().

I'm on Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) since that seems to be what using `includes` is buying you in this situation (here, `User has_many :orders` and `Order belongs_to :user`):

```
puts Order.where({
  id: Order.left_outer_joins(:user).where(users: { id: [nil, 1] })
}).to_sql

# SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"
# WHERE "orders"."id" IN (
#   SELECT "orders"."id" FROM "orders"
#   LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "orders"."user_id"
#   WHERE ("users"."id" = 1 OR "users"."id" IS NULL)
# )
```

It's possible (though I'm just guessing right now) Rails is kind of self-optimizing..it only really needed the `LEFT OUTER JOINS` in order to select all the columns from `Company`, but since you added it into a condition, it no longer needs to grab all the columns, it only needs to grab `users.id`, so it just doesn't do the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
User.where(id: User.joins(:company).where(companies: {id: 0}).references(:companies))
```

But I don't understand why you need wrap it all in a `where`?

I think `User.includes(:company).where(companies: {id: 0})` return all users you need.

Comment: This does not work for my situation, because it also needs to return 'User's for which the join does not yield any results. Your suggestion omits those altogether.

My actual query uses different tables with different conditions. It all has to do with program structure. I've simplified it for the purpose of this question.